# Determining possible triangle from lengths of line segments

Tags: java, interview-questions, programming-challenge

This [Codility challenge](http://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/triangle) is to take an array of integers representing lengths of line segments, and determine whether or not it is possible to choose three distinct segments to form a triangle.  (The sum of the lengths of any two sides must exceed the length of the remaining side.)  Assume that `A` contains at most one million `int`s.

Complexity requirements:

- Expected worst-case time complexity is O(n log(n));
- Expected worst-case space complexity is O(n), not counting the input array `A` itself.

This is my solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 6
        int n = A.length;

        if (n>1000000000) return -1;

        Arrays.sort(A);
        int p=0;
        int q=p+1;
        int r=q+1;
        for (;r<n;p++,q++,r++){
            if(A[p]+A[q]>A[r] && A[q]+A[r]>A[p] &&  A[r]+A[p]>A[q])
               return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I don't how to achieve 100% correctness. I get only 93%.

Comment: please include the basics of the problem from the link. i clicked the link, and it wanted me to do the test, this could be considered spam by some, trying to lure people to a site.

Comment: @Malachi: Since it's not a blatant intent to spam, it shouldn't apply here.  However, it would be useful to have a better reference to this problem (which the OP may have to provide).

Comment: @Malachi: You may also suggest the tag wiki for this new tag.

Comment: @Jamal I suggested a tag wiki for that, I wasn't sure what it was at first, I had to go to the main site first, I have never heard of that site until today, but I can see it becoming a thing here on code review. similar to other sites where you compete by writing code, etc.

Comment: @Malachi: It is on SO, so it should be okay.

Comment: @Malachi: On that note, you could also refer to SO's tag wiki.  I skipped one of the suggestions because I wasn't sure if it was best to use here as it sounded a tad promotional.

Comment: Is this a code review or an algorithm review?  Are they the same here?

Comment: Hint:  you are not examining all possible triples, which is implied in your question.  How can you check all possible triples in n log n time?  Can you think of ways to incorporate a binary search into your algorithm?

Comment: I have run code against this codility, and I believe their system has a bug. I get 93% as well, and I have manually checked my code and the item it tells me I get wrong is not, in fact wrong when I run it myself. The result they get in their environment is different to the one I get.

Comment: Huh, OK, I got 100%, using a different approach. I think there's a problem with Codility's Arrays.binarySearch().

Comment: Thank you to all! Have I to move to stackedoverflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you must do several things to ensure you get the maximum marks.

1. Ensure that negative numbers are checked for.
2. Handle the `MAX_INT` overflow issue which could arise.

   > You know `4 + 5 > 7` is same as `5 > (7 - 4)`. Yes I know you are grinning ;)

   This suggested solution is correct for this.

These two individual points should allow you to achieve the maximum score. Now I would just like to quickly go over some theory behind why this solution works.

**Time complexities**

It seems people keep asking you to address the "consecutive elements". You have already done this through the use of `Arrays.sort()`. This Java sort algorithm is referred to as a "tuned Quicksort" ( See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) ).

> The sorting algorithm is a tuned quicksort, adapted from Jon L. Bentley and M. Douglas McIlroy's "Engineering a Sort Function", Software-Practice and Experience, Vol. 23(11) P. 1249-1265 (November 1993). This algorithm offers n*log(n) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance.
>   Quicksort is well known for its `O( n log n )` time complexity (excluding extreme cases).

After this you do a single iteration over the array, which is considered `O(n)`. When we add the two time complexities together we are given `O( 2n log n)` where constants are considered insignificant for Big-O notation. So to clarify this simplifies down to `O(n log n)` which was the upper bound of the problem.

**How sorting solves non-consecutive elements**

Once the array is sorted it is true that only consecutive triples need to be considered.

Consider the following array: `{1,2,6,6,8}`

Whilst it may be true that `(1, 6, 6)` is triangular, and is non-consecutive. It can also be proven that if that value is triangular then any number which lies between the initial 1, and 6 will also be triangular.

From this we can see that in the sort array, for each non-consecutive triangular triples which exists there also exists an consecutive triple.

**Simplification from sorting**

The sort operation allows you to simplify you checks later, and decrease execution time. When checking for negative number, you only need check the lowest number in the triple, as if this is `>= 0` it is given the follow values must be `>=` that initial value.

This mean you only need check one value for negativity, not three.

This can be extended further into the actual triangular checks. If it is true that the smallest two numbers in the triple are larger than the largest number when summed, then all three statements are true.

> 1) A[P] + A[Q] > A[R]
>
> 2) A[Q] + A[R] > A[P]
>
> 3) A[R] + A[P] > A[Q]

Remembering the algorithm change to this, so these would be evaluated as

```
A[P] > (A[R] - A[Q])
```

Because we can guarantee that `A[P] < A[Q] < A[R]` due to A being sorted, we only need perform the one check above.

Comment: cool. But I didn't know about the _"It can also be proven [......] be triangular"_ part, can you provide a link?

Comment: I said can be proven ;), I haven't found a link which in fact proves this as of yet. But if you consider a large set of numbers, and try extreme cases, you will see it holds. Unfortunately I never continued my Maths further, so I do not have the knowledge required to draw up a full Mathematical proof for you.

Comment: Thank you! So I have to change the if with A[P]>(A[R]-A[Q]) in case the first number of triangle is negative!

Comment: @user31565 `A[P]>(A[R]-A[Q])` is to prevent the problem of an overflow exception if `A[P] + A[Q] > MAX_INT`, for this problem you are required to ignore negative numbers as they are invalid. Which is why you first do a check of `A[P] >= 0`.

Comment: If you could show me the code I will understand better :) I misunderstood!

Comment: `if( (A[P] > 0) && (A[P] > (A[R]-A[Q]) ) { // triangular }`

Comment: Perfect 100% :)

Comment: Suppose there are some values `P`, `Q`, and `R` such that `P < Q`, `Q < R`, and `A[P] > A[R] - A[Q]`. Since `R - 2 >= P` and `R - 2 >= Q`, and since the array is sorted, it follows that `A[R - 2] >= A[P]` and `A[R - 1] >= A[Q]`. From that it follows that `A[R - 2] > A[R] - A[R - 1]`. In other words, if there are three entries _anywhere_ in the array that can form a triangle, then there are three consecutive entries that can form a triangle. That's why it's sufficient to check only consecutive entries.

Comment: It is not O(2n log n) but it is O(n + n log n), and because n log n is worst time complexity it is treated just like O(n log n). Please update your answer

Answer (score 2):

Funny things that we(human) know that 2,147,483,647 + 1 = 2,147,483,648 but computer thinks [otherwise](http://ideone.com/QX7N6z). *Ahhh! see*, so now what to do?

You know `4 + 5 > 7` is same as `5 > (7 - 3)`. Yes I know you are grinning ;)

And also as [200_success suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/33874/26200) you are considering consecutive elements but problem definition say otherwise.